# Gnome login screen "loops" after computer has slept

Tags: 16.04, gnome, hardware, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome

Using Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME (which I added later, the original version has Unity), with a Dell Inspiron 15-3531.

After I turn off my computer (with the power button), or make it sleep (shut the lid), at the GNOME login screen which shows the profiles, I click mine, then enter my password. For about 2 seconds it seems like the computer will unlock as usual, but it then loops back to the gray screen with the profiles. It still responds to an extent, as it tells me if my password is incorrect.

I've only been able to temporarily fix it by a full shutdown, or by removing the battery for a minute. Granted, my laptop is old so it could just be that.

Edit: my `.Xauthority` file is not owned by root but by my user. Creating a new profile does work, however I would not necessarily want to use this new profile as my main. Any suggestions on how to change that? Renaming `.Xauthority` on my main profile returns "invalid user".

Comment: @Redbob My post has been edited after testing out those solutions.

Comment: So even after renaming .Xauthority didn't solved? Have you tried to create another account to see if you have the same problem?

Comment: @Redbob .Xauthority did not have the issue as described, and even attempting it did not work. I will try to make another account.

Comment: @Redbob refer to edit 2

Comment: It's strange... when we rename .Xauthority, then a new gui session automatically creates a new .Xauthority file.  Perhaps some files or some folders are not accessible. If you `ls ~ -lha`, is there any file owned to root?

Comment: @Redbob yes, they're not the majority but there are a few with root.

Comment: So you must chown all of them to your account. Execute this: `sudo chown username  /home/username -hR`, where _username_ is the name of your account.

Comment: Thank you @Redbob, I'm going to tentatively say that worked. If you would be so kind as to make that an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, graphical interfaced (GUI) session is not successfully due to several situations, the most common are:

- Corruption of `~/.Xauthority` file: this should be corrected by just renaming or deleting this file; at next gui-login, this file is automatically recreated;
- Inaccessibility of some config files and/or folders within $HOME folder: It can be corrected by *chowning* this files for user owner.  Typing

  `sudo chown username /home/username -hR`

will grant all contents within $HOME folder to be accessible to *username* account;

- Not enough space for `/home` partition: It's necessary to delete not-necessary content or resize this partition, to allow a successful gui-session.