# Stuck in login screen loop 16.04 Ubuntu

Tags: login

Currently I am stuck in a login screen loop in Ubuntu 16.04.  I have tried every suggestion that I have found on every forum and, as I am fairly new to Linux, I am at a loss for what to do.

I have tried purging all graphics drivers and reinstalling them.  I have performed a distro upgrade.  I have purged lightdm and reinstalled it.  This problem is fairly pressing as well as I am in my last two weeks of my college courses which are online and I have my final projects stored on this machine. I am not sure what to do.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your home directory Permissions? Have you checked this one? Who is owner of your home directory? (login to one if ttys and check, if those were right, try remove `mv ~/.gconf ~/.gconf.bak` and try again

Comment: Look at [my answer to this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954300/gnome-login-screen-loops-after-computer-has-slept/954389). If solves, please upvote to it